# Why does switching desktops with AutoHotKey make my taskbar icons highlight orange?

Tags: autohotkey, taskbar, windows-virtual-desktop

I am yet to find a method to switch desktops that doesn't result in the taskbar icons highlighting orange.

[e.g. the following script wreaks this havoc on my taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYGaN.png)

```
^#Right::
send, ^#{Right}
return

^#Left::
send, ^#{Left}
return
```

What methods are there to get around this?

Comment: Is there any more info that you can provide on this issue? The script works fine for me as is: I am currently not able to reproduce what you are experiencing.

Comment: So for me to reproduce on my system, I: 1) open a couple desktops. I usually use 3, 2) put one program on each desktop, 3) switch between desktops. When I use the original windows shortcuts to switch, the window on the new desktop is selected. But when I use the autohotkey shortcuts, then the window on the new desktop remains inactive and its icon starts highlighting orange. Is it just my system or is this a more common issue on windows 10? (Education, 64-bit)

Comment: So ^#XButton2::Send ^#{Right} return causes the issue while ^#XButton2::^#Right return doesn't. Obviously something about the way the send command works that I don't understand.

Comment: you could try rawsend see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes when I switch desktop, the application that's focused on that desktop becomes highlighted in the task bar.
>
> Example:
> On desktop A, I have Firefox:
> [image: untitled]
>
> On desktop B I have Steam (note that Firefox is pinned to my task bar, which is why it's visible on this desktop):
> [image: untitled2]
>
> When I switch from A to B, Steam becomes highlighted:
> [image: untitled3]
> (It's possible to stop the blinking by explicitly selecting the blinking window with the mouse or alt+tab.)
>
> When I switch back to A, Firefox also becomes highlighted (and Steam stays visible in the taskbar because it is highlighted):
> [image: untitled4]
>
> This doesn't always happen; I'm not sure if it depends on the programs or where the mouse/keyboard focus is when switching desktops. That said, it happens far too often, to the point where it defeats the point of having multiple desktops at all.
>
> (The problem isn't limited to Firefox and Steam, the same thing also happens with other programs like Explorer.)

https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/VD.ahk#cool-fixes

> `WinActivate` taskbar before switching and `WinMinimize` taskbar after arriving

```
    ;activate taskbar before
    WinActivate, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    WinWaitActive, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    DllCall(SwitchDesktop, "ptr", IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal, "UPtr", IVirtualDesktop, "UInt")
    DllCall(SwitchDesktop, "ptr", IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal, "UPtr", IVirtualDesktop, "UInt")
    WinMinimize, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
```

https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/VD.ahk/blob/6fc1b2b7ff9ab53c8530c0d9a2e01a6617c064f4/VD.ahk#L555-L560

actual source:  https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop/issues/59#issuecomment-317613971